# Check if two areas are in contact

Tags: c#, rectangles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding the overlapping area of two rectangles (in C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551243/finding-the-overlapping-area-of-two-rectangles-in-c)

I have two areas identified by top left and bottom right corners (fig.1).

In c#, how can I test if they are in contact (fig.2)?

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551243/finding-the-overlapping-area-of-two-rectangles-in-c?rq=1

Comment: @Burgos [`Rectangle.IntersectsWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle.intersectswith.aspx) is actually more specific to the problem. I would say not *exactly* a duplicate.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Let's say you have two `Rectangle`s which are `r1` and `r2`, you can check whether they intersects with each other by this:

```
if(r1.IntersectsWith(r2))
{
    // Intersect
}
```

---

If you need the exact area which they intersects with each other, you can do this:

```
Rectangle intersectArea = Rectangle.Intersect(r1, r2);
```

You can check the documentation: [`Rectangle.IntersectsWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle.intersectswith.aspx), [`Rectangle.Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y10fyck0.aspx)

---

**Additional important note:**

I've just checked that if the two rectangles just touch each other on an edge, `Rectangle.Intersect` returns a rectangle with one dimension is zero , **however** `Rectangle.IntersectsWith` will return `false`. So you need to note that.

For example, `Rectangle.Intersect` on `{X=0,Y=0,Width=10,Height=10}` and `{X=10,Y=0,Width=10,Height=10}` will return `{X=10,Y=0,Width=0,Height=10}`.

If you hope to get `true` also if they just touch each other, change the condition to:

```
if(Rectangle.Intersect(r1, r2) != Rectangle.Empty)
{
    // Intersect or contact (just touch each other)
}
```

Comment: @AnatoleBAUDOUIN There's something important that I've just added.

Answer (score 18):

If you don't want to depend on `System.Drawing`:

Let's note:

- `X1`, `Y1`, `X2`, `Y2` : the coordinates of the points of the first rectangle (with `X1 < X2` and `Y1 < Y2`)
- `X1'`, `Y1'`, `X2'`, `Y2'` : the coordinates of the points of the second rectangle (with `X1' < X2'` and `Y1' < Y2'`)

There is intersection if and only if:

```
(X2' >= X1 && X1' <= X2) && (Y2' >= Y1 && Y1' <= Y2)
```