# Find centre of circle with maximum point enclosed

Tags: algorithm, geometry

I am giving a circle of radius `R` and `N` points on `x-y` plan , I want to draw a circle of radius `R` such that it maximize the number of points enclosed.

**My Approach:** 
If there exists a circle `C` that encloses `M` points, then by slightly moving C it will touch at least two points.

So, essentially we just need to check all circles which touch (at least) 2 points:

- For each pair of points in the given set, construct a circle with
  radius R that touches both points. For each point pair there are at
  most two such circles.
- For each constructed circle, check for each of the given points is
  inside it. Return the circle that encloses the maximum number of
  points.
  **Time Complexity O(N^3)**

Is there any algorithm which i can reduce my time complexity ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151162/find-the-most-points-enclosed-in-a-fixed-size-circle

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-is-an-algorithm-for-enclosing-the-maximum-number-of-points-in-a-2-D-plane-with-a-fixed-radius-circle

Comment: This is not exactly your approach, this is a well known approach.