# make control reddish in windows forms

Tags: winforms

In Winforms, I want two controls to appear shadowed-red if they are intersecting. 
I want all their properties to remain, but as long as they are intersecting, I want them to have a reddish shadow.
Is there a property that deals with this? Any other simple way to handle this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, you would have to loop through all controls and check if their rectangles intersect manually.

[What is an Efficient algorithm to find Area of Overlapping Rectangles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244452/what-is-an-efficient-algorithm-to-find-area-of-overlapping-rectangles)

Comment: Thanks! This is definately useful to me, But I meant - is there a way to make the control to have a reddish taint, while maintaining all of its properties?

Comment: You would have to change the fore color and keep track of the original values. All windows forms controls have a tag property, that usually unused, that you can use if you don't feel like subclassing or keeping the values some where else.