# Algorithm to check whether given rectangles form a square

Tags: algorithm, sorting, geometry

Input : N rectangles. The coordinates for the rectangles are given.

Output : To check whether they form  a square or not.

- There can be overlapping among the rectangles.

I have solved for the case in which rectangles are parallel to the **X** and **Y** axis.

Soln :

Since the area of square is a perfect square ,so
**(Sum of area of total rectangles - Overlapping in between them )** should be a perfect square.

Now find the min. value of **X** coordinate of all the rectangles and max. value of **Y** coordinate. 
If they form a square then **| min(x)-max(y) |** is the length of the square. 
Now just find the sum of the area of the rectangles considering the overlaps. 
If it's equal to area of square with length **| min(x)-max(y) |**. Bingo !!

Complexity : **O(n*n)**

How to solve for general case ?

Comment: It does not guarantee that there are no gaps in the square.

Comment: What are the sizes of rectangles and how large are they coordinates?

Answer (score 2):

Assume that all rectangles form the square, but edges of rectangles are not parallel to axes.

Then the square has four vertices: top, bottom, right and left. The top vertex of the square has y-coordinate = max of y-coordinates of all vertices of all rectangles. So on for other three vertices: bottom (min y), right (max x), and left (min x).

To find the angle of the square it's sufficient only two vertices: bottom and right.
Let's bottom vertex coordinates are (someX, minY), and right vertex coordinates are (maxX, someY).
Then angle is `atan((someY-minY)/(maxX-someX))`. In C/C++/Java/C# you can use the function `atan2`.

After, rotate all rectangles on `-angle`, and then you can apply your algorithm for rectangles that are parallel for axes.

Answer (score 0):

Mark's answer is correct if you already have an O(N^2) solution for the no-rotations case. However the toughest part of this problem is actually the inital no-rotations case (finding the total area of overlap to be exact).

I am not sure if you considered the case of multiple overlaps (more than 2 rectangles overlapping in one spot), but for those who are curious about finding the overlapping area:

There exists an interesting sweep algorithm that can be tuned to O(N log N) with use of some data structures.

Check this link if you are interested: [Efficient algorithm to find Area of Overlapping Rectangles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244452/what-is-an-efficient-algorithm-to-find-area-of-overlapping-rectangles)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this in O(n). The sides of the rectangles that form part of the final square's sides will have smallest [Y-intercept](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-intercept) and the smallest [X-intercept](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-intercept#x-intercepts). You can use this to identify the sides that are part of the final boundary, by keeping track of the sides which make smallest X and Y intercepts.

Every side that that qualifies as the smallest intercept maker will be tested against the min/max value along the line and those values will be updated.

At the end, compare the min-max gap between the min-Y-intercept and min-X-intercept line segments and if they have the same length, then the final boundary is a square.

I can provide some pseudo-code if this is not clear. Let me know. I've added a figure to illustrate below:
[image]