# Given 4 "right" rectangles (right rectangles have edges parallel to x or y), find the area that is covered by any of them

Tags: algorithm, geometry, rectangles

Help please. I'm working on an algorithm with this requirement.

Given 4 "right" rectangles (right rectangles have edges parallel to x or y), find the area that is covered by any of them

For example, the area in grey are covered by any of those 4 rectangles in the picture below.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JocvC.png)

I am not quite understand the question. Could someone help me please?

Comment: Do you need the area of _any_ rectangle or the area of _all_ rectangles combined? The first would be easy, it's just the height of one rectangle times its width. The second is a rather complex question. What do you have so far?

Comment: "I am not quite understand the question" - I don't think we'll be able to give an answer if you don't understand what you are asking. What are the expected inputs and outputs? Can you put a specific example? (not just a picture, but an example input to the algorithm and its corresponding output).

Comment: One possibility: sum of the areas of the 4 rectangles - sum of the intersections of 2 rectangles + sum of the intersections of 3 rectangles - the intersection of all 4 rectangles

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an Efficient algorithm to find Area of Overlapping Rectangles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244452/what-is-an-efficient-algorithm-to-find-area-of-overlapping-rectangles)

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use the [Inclusion-Exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) applied to areas.
Here is the 3 rectangle case:

```
A = Area( R[0]) + Area( R[1]) + Area( R[2])
  - ( Area( inter( R[0], R[1])) 
    + Area( inter( R[0], R[2]))
    + Area( inter( R[1], R[2]))
    )
  + Area( inter( inter( R[0], R[1]), R[2]))
```

where

```
Area(R) gives the area of a rectangle R, and 
inter( R, S) is the rectangle that is the intersection of R and S
```

The 4 rectangle case will be a little tedious, but I suspect it would still be easier to program long-hand rather than using loops.