# How to find the Area of Overlapping Rectangles

Tags: python, optimization, area, aabb

I'm trying to get the area of overlapping rectangles without the intersection. The visualization of the rectangles look like the below:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA--------------BBB
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA--------------BBB
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA--------------BBB
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA--------------BBB
                BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
                BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
                BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
                BBBBBB-----------CCCCCCCC
                BBBBBB-----------CCCCCCCC
                BBBBBB-----------CCCCCCCC
                      CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
                      CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
                      CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
                      CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
```

I'm following the answer from this [url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244452/what-is-an-efficient-algorithm-to-find-area-of-overlapping-rectangles), and currently the below code is helpful for me:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.zeros((100, 100))
B = np.zeros((100, 100))

A[rect1.top : rect1.bottom,  rect1.left : rect1.right] = 1
B[rect2.top : rect2.bottom,  rect2.left : rect2.right] = 1

area_of_union     = np.sum((A + B) > 0)
area_of_intersect = np.sum((A + B) > 1)
```

What is the most efficient way of getting the area of the rectangles (with 3 or more rectangles) and how do I do it in python? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please explain how the data is represented, and maybe provide a sample/example of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can access the corners of the Rectangles you can use the shapely module and use some set operations like difference and union. [Documentation](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#) says that operations are highly optimized.

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point

# define rectangles as polygons using their border points
A = Polygon(((0, 0), (2, 0), (2, 2), (0, 2)))

B = Polygon(((-1, -1), (-1, 1), (1, 1), (1, -1)))

C = Polygon(((0, 0), (-2, 0), (-2, -2), (0, -2)))

print(A.area)  # 4.0
print(B.area)  # 4.0
print(C.area)  # 4.0

b_without_a = B.difference(A)
b_without_c = B.difference(C)

print(b_without_a.area)  # 3.0
print(b_without_c.area)  # 3.0

total = b_without_a.intersection(b_without_c)

print(total.area)  # 2.0
```